# Shorthand for \lstinline{ ... }?

Tags: listings, code, inline

I'm finding that I need to use `\lstinline{...}` a lot.

I rather like the way that SX does inline code. Just enclose in back-ticks.

Is this functionality available in LaTeX, or is it possible for make LaTeX work similarly?

Comment: `\lstMakeShortInline[⟨options⟩]\``

Comment: @ana If it solved your problem, please consider accepting Manuel's answer by clicking on the tickmark below his vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), in the documentation, you can find more info in section 4.17, as @Jubobs said. This command will make `` ` `` active so you can input verbatim content this way: `` some `verbatim` code ``

```
\lstMakeShortInline[⟨options⟩]`
```